# 2重にAutowiredされたクラスだけmock化することは可能なのか知りたい。

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

SpringBootにおける依存性注入、及びユニットテストについての質問です。

テスト対象クラスから見て、2重にAutowiredしているクラスだけをMock化してテストすることは可能でしょうか？

具体的には、下記のようなテストをしたいです。
・テスト対象はMainServiceImpl
・SubMainServiceImplはモック化せず、されている処理をそのまま使う
・SubSubMainServiceImplをモック化し、subsubSayHello()の出力文字列を変更する

「そもそもテストクラスを切り分けて、直接依存するクラスだけをモック化しろ」というご意見もあると思いますが、上記が技術的には可能なのか知りたいです。

```
//テストで直接動かしたいクラス
@Service
public class MainServiceImpl implements MainService {

  @Autowired
  private SubMainService subMainService;

  @Override
  public String mainSayHello() {
    return "MainSayHello. Also..." + subMainService.subSayHello();
  }
}
```

```
//MainServiceImplが依存しているクラス
@Service
public class SubMainServiceImpl implements SubMainService {

  @Autowired
  private SubSubMainService subSubMainService;

  @Override
  public String subSayHello() {
    return "SubSayHello. Also..." + subSubMainService.subSubSayHello();
  }
}
```

```
//SubMainServiceImplが依存しているクラス
@Service
public class SubSubMainServiceImpl implements SubSubMainService {

  @Override
  public String subSubSayHello() {
      return "SubSubSayHello";
    }
}
```

ちなみに、@InjectMocksと@Mocksを使って、直接依存するクラスをMock化する手法については認識済みです。

```
//直接依存するクラスをMock化するテスト
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class MockMainServiceTest {

  @InjectMocks
  MainServiceImpl mainService;

  @Mock
  SubMainService subMainService;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }

  @Test
  public void サブクラスをMock化(){
    doReturn("SubMainServiceはMock化されたよ").when(subMainService).subSayHello();
    Assert.assertThat(mainService.mainSayHello() ,is("MainSayHello. Also...SubMainServiceはMock化されたよ"));
  }
}
```

仕様技術
SpringBoot 2.5.4
JUnit 4.2
Java 1.8

Answer (score 1):

質問文のテストコードは、コンテナを利用していません(もし本当にそのようなテストがしたいのであれば、 `@SpringBootTest`, `@RunWith` を付与する必要はありません(付与しなくとも結果は変わりません))。

コンテナマネージドなオブジェクトをテストするには、次のようなコードになります。
テスト対象を`@Autowired`でインジェクションし、モックSpring Bean生成は[`@MockBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.4/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html)を利用します。

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class MockMainServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    MainService mainService;

    @MockBean
    SubMainService subMainService;

    @Test
    public void サブクラスをMock化() {
        doReturn("SubMainServiceはMock化されたよ").when(subMainService).subSayHello();
        Assert.assertThat(mainService.mainSayHello(), is("MainSayHello. Also...SubMainServiceはMock化されたよ"));
    }
}
```

本来行いたいテストは上のコードのようなものだとすると、`SubSubMainService` だけモック化する場合も同じように書けば良いです。

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class MockMainServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    MainService mainService;

    @MockBean
    SubSubMainService subSubMainService;

    @Test
    public void サブサブクラスをMock化() {
        doReturn("SubSubMainServiceはMock化されたよ").when(subSubMainService).subSubSayHello();
        Assert.assertThat(mainService.mainSayHello(),
            is("MainSayHello. Also...SubSayHello. Also...SubSubMainServiceはMock化されたよ"));
    }
}
```

参考:

- [7.26. Testing > Mocking and Spying Beans](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.4/reference/htmlsingle/#features.testing.spring-boot-applications.mocking-beans)